# How to Gathering a UITextField and a UILabel value and sending to an email

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have setup everything with the in-app email. I'm trying to gather the UITextField value and UILabel value then send the information to the "body" of an email. Here is the line of code that I believe needs tweaked:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tex2.text %@ label2.text %@"];
[composer setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) call is missing the [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) and [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) parameters:

```
// format your body text. I have added a couple of \n characters to move the label text to the third line.
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tex2.text %@\n\nlabel2.text %@", yourTextField.text, yourLabel.text];
```

Comment: Works! Is there a way to list the items vertically? It reads like this in the email:  text 5 text 7

Comment: @TWcode You just need to embed some newlines. I'll update my answer.

Comment: How can I double space between text?

Comment: @TWCode You just need a second newline character :)

Comment: My answer was the exact same as @RedBlueThing, and was posted 1 minute before, so you can also upvote mine as well.  ;—P

Answer (score 0):

If you define your textField and label in your header, you can just get the value like this:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tex2.text %@ label2.text %@",myTextField.text, myLabel.text];
```